# Webdav server not working on window 10

Tags: webdav

One of my users have upgraded to windows 10 and since then has not able to copy files to our webdav server.

Below is the error we get every time we copy/drag from a file from windows folder to webdav folder.

> can't read from source file or disk

The following has been tried, has worked in previous windows versions but not working on windows 10:

Changing the below registry settings

Navigate to the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters`
In this key, change the value of `BasicAuthLevel` to `2`
I have tried both of the below

- Map network drive
- Add network location
- Tried using webdav client Cyberduck but it does not work on windows 10

Is there any other change of setting or an alternate recommended client that I can try?

Comment: Considering webdav is a generic protocol, not necessarily related to Tridion.. should work ootb. Have you tried to map to any other server and/or are you able to transfer files to other mapped drives? I would start with my troubleshooting there..

Comment: The maximum file size that can be transferred using WebDAV is limited to just under 4GB

Comment: Are you trying to use HTTP basic auth over an unsecured connection?  Micosoft is making it harder to get that to work in every new Windows version.

Comment: what version of SDL Tridion are you exactly using?

Comment: it seems some issue with win 10, superuser.com/questions/975251/webdav-error-after-upgrading-to-windows-10

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, i am using SDl Tridion 2011.